# idea, run findbugs with ant project

Tags: java, xml, ant, findbugs

when I started programming I wrote small programs, and I can just click "run" and that's all. and I used findbugs in idea, and I just compiled my program, and then I clicked "run findbugs". But not I am working, and I have a big project. We use ant. So my question-how could I run findbugs in IDEA, using findbugs plugin? I found only solution write in build.xml code and after build it generates me .xml file with bugs. But could I get bugs in idea ? I want fast orienter, fast fix bugs, in idea. don't open xml/html. of course I have to do it after full build my application. But what I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking for a FindBugs plugin for idea. Try searching for "FindBugs plugin idea" in a search engine of your choice.

Comment: yes, but you can't just run it there. because you don't have .class files, because of ant.